# How would I ask for a fade haircut plus a little bit off the top in chinese?

Tags: translation

In the US I usually ask for the following:

A #2 (top) to #1 (bottom) fade on the sides and neck

The neckline grows way too low so I ask them to cut that to a certain length

Half an inch off the top

Cut the sideburns to a certain point

I really don't know how to ask for this in China, and I searched online and the answers are rather inconsistent. Any ideas?

Comment: Show them a picture

Comment: I guess that would work, thanks @julian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A #2 (top) to #1 (bottom) fade on the sides and neck

上面二号，旁边和脖子一号的渐变式发型

> Half an inch off the top

上面剪短半寸

> Cut the sideburns to [this] point

把鬓角剪到这里

I had some trouble finding a translation of neckline, especially since the definition of neckline as in beard isn’t even in English dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

> "The neckline grows way too low so I ask them to cut that to a certain
>   length",

Try 把后面的头发往上剪 or 把后面的头发往上剃一些

> Cut the sideburns to a certain point

Try 把鬓角往上剃一些.